# How many rows in a DE can an AMPscript lookup reasonable handle without affecting sending performance?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a DE with transactions with over a million records. In an email I want to check if the contact made a purchase and if so, grab the coupon code they used with that purchase. Will the size of the DE affect email sending performance?

Answer (score 0):

Any customisation in email will atleast have a slight impact on performance. I would suggest you to use [Lookup order rows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuporderedrows.htm) since you have more than 1 million records.

Also, if you are more concerned on email performance then you ask SQL query to do the heavy duty. Add a new column called coupon code in target data extension, populate the coupon code with the target data extension.

In this case you don't have to write complex logic in ampscripts.